# popen() gives error: no such file or directory

Tags: php, popen

I am using php version 5.2.17. I have a site build in php and testing it under IIS 5.1 on localhost (windows).

I want to run a lengthy PHP script in background, thereby allowing the user to continue using the site (navigation).

I am trying using popen like this:

```
$cmd='c:\\php\\php.exe c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\download.php';
pclose(popen('start /B '.$cmd, 'r'));
```

This gives error:

```
PHP Warning: popen(c:\php\php.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot\download.php,r) [function.popen]: No such file or directory.
```

Any clues are highly appreciated.

Comment: The above script works fine via command line and executes the php code in download.php.

Comment: Does the webserver have permissions to c:\php\php.exe ? (apologies, not familiar with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first execute cmd and then call php over cmd like explained here: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/751763-popen-windows

Comment: Basically, popen gives the same error for any parameters i pass. no matter its 'start ...' or 'cmd..' the error is the same. looks like its some php settings issue or permissions issue. cant figure out.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: i changed the file security of Download.php in IIS and set the user to IWAM(launch IIS Process account).

Thanks for ull experts who showed concern.